# Fetching feeds by date

Tags: php, xml, feed

I want to be fetching feeds from a site on a daily basis. I only want to fetch the present day's feeds alone. Is there a way i can specify the date i intend to fetch as a parameter or i will just need to check the date of each fetched feed and stop fetching when the date is not the present day's date?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends on the "source" of the feeds and what kind of api is offered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can only happen if the people who created the feed allow you to specify a date to fetch as a parameter. There isn't really a standardized API for these types of things, and every RSS feed provider is different. I'd suggest emailing the site owners to see if they have something like that.

If you don't want to email them, or they don't have the requested API, you are going to have to pull the whole RSS feed, parse is, and then figure out what to do from there.